# Conditional chaining in JavaScript or TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, joi

Is there a syntax to add a function to a chain under conditions?

In this example, I would like `myKey` to be `Joi.string().required()` if `modifier === true`, but just `Joi.string()` if it is `false`:

```
function customJoi(modifier) {
  return Joi.object({
    myKey: Joi.string() //#If(modifier) .required() #EndIf
  });
}
```

I know I could do without this feature, with multiple steps. I'm just wondering if there is a nice way to write it concisely for large objects.

Comment: @Touffy :shrug: OP states "conditional chaining" which seems to describe the problem pretty well and the question elaborates; IMO it's fine.

Comment: I agree, once you read it carefully it's a good description. But who reads carefully nowadays ? (see first comment on this post…). Maybe just write "optional" in italics or something ?

Comment: @Touffy I think most people who answered and commented here did read correctly :)

Comment: @Touffy My bad - happens sometimes to me - hope I get pardoned.. ;)

Comment: @Touffy It literally doesn't say "optional" anywhere?

Comment: @DaveNewton They said that because someone posted a link on _conditional chaining_ (`?.`).

Comment: @Seeven That was a link on [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) tho. But :shrug: we can agree to disagree; I think it was clear.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes I meant "optional" chaining x)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take [`optional`](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.5.0#anyoptional), if not required.

```
myKey: Joi.string()[modifier ? 'required' : 'optional']()
```

Comment: Thanks, I think that's the best we can get :) Although one limitation is that you have to have a fallback method for the ternary operator to work, as `undefined` doesn't seem to be acceptable.

Comment: True. Though I guess in a controlled environment you could define a "noop" method on any chainable you design, so you always have that option. Or… *gasp*… define it on Object.prototype and be despised by all your coworkers.

Answer (score 5):

You can achieve that with a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

```js
function customJoi(modifier) {
    return Joi.object({
        myKey: modifier ? Joi.string().required() : Joi.string()
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a good answer too, but I'll accept Nina Scholz's answer because it's closer to what I was looking for, especially for longer chains. Although one advantage of your method is you don't need a fallback method for the ternary operator.